# How can I detect an invalid floating point number before performing any floating point operations on it

Tags: c++, gcc, fpu

I have an application that loads binary `float` values out of a file. I have discovered that the "producer" of this file is occasionally putting values into it which are not valid floating point bit patterns, specifically `0x80426c51` (there may be others). When I do an `fread()` of this this value into a floating point address (that was casted to a `void *`) completes successfully. But if I try and access the `float` to do anything, an exception occurs. I cannot even cast the `float` to a `double` since it is not a valid `float`. I think I need something like `fpclassify()` which can take a `float`. But I don't know if such a function/macro exists. My target operating system's `<math.h>` does not even have `fpclassify()`. I am using gcc version 4.8.1.9 on a "non-mainstream" operating system (not Windows/Mac/Linux) with a core-i7 instruction set. Although I am using C++, I am not using any standard template libraries, nor RTTI because this is an embedded system.

Note: In the short term, I have modified the "generator" program, but I don't like that as a long term solution as I may not have any control over the final "generator" program.

Comment: `fpclassify` for floats is in C++11. Do you not have C++11 support? Or is the problem that you have a freestanding implementation that doesn't supply `fpclassify`?

Comment: I'm likely tired and missing something, but why is that an invalid bit pattern for a float?  (It looks like a subnormal, but that should be fine.)

Comment: What do your embeded system docs say about denormal numbers?  @OliverCharlesworth Some floating point implementations do not support denormal numbers.

Comment: @1201 but the OP does mention he's on i7.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth "a core-i7 instruction set" - are there non-intel CPUs that run this?  And even on Intel CPUs, operations with denormal numbers can result in FPU exceptions instead of a result.

Comment: @Brian: I do not have `fpclassify`

Comment: @Oliver: Honestly, I'm not certain why that value breaks. When I hover over it, the debugger gives me the floating point number that I was expecting. But then the system locks up. We have an FPU exception handler. But that does not seem to be getting called. That is a completely different issue. Actually upon closer examination, we do have `denormalized operand` exception enabled. Maybe I need to disable that during the file load.